# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException error when doing a post request using @MapKeyJoinColumn in a @JoinTable

Tags: hashmap, mapkeyjoincolumn

Good day

I am trying to create a new instance of a class by sending a post request from Postman to a Spring webservice. For some obscure reason I get a "HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported" error. Below are my classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="loanRequests")
public class LoanRequest {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id ;

    private String name;
    
    private Integer amount;
    
    private String usernameId;
    
    @Value("false")
    public Boolean isApproved;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "loanRequest_user_mapping",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "loanRequests_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "users_username", referencedColumnName = "username")})
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "roles_rolename")
    public Map<Role, User> users;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(unique=true, name = "username")
private String username;

    private String password;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "roles_rolename")
    private Role role;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Payment> payments;
    
    //Is mappedBy nodig
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Collection<LoanRequest> loanRequests;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "rolename")
    private String rolename;
}
```

```
public class LoanRequestDto {

    public Long id;

    public String name;

    public Integer amount;

    public Boolean isApproved;

    public String usernameId;

    public Map<Role, User> usernameIds;
}
```

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<LoanRequest> createLoanRequest(@RequestBody LoanRequestDto loanRequestDto) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(loanRequestService.createLoanRequest(loanRequestDto), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Postman POST request body: JSON-raw

{
"name" : "Application1",
"amount" : 3,
"isApproved" : false,
"usernameId" : "BOR"
}

I interpreted the problem as that the fieldnames in my JSON code is incorrect, but it seems to be correct. So perhaps the problem has to do with the annotations that I am using? I will appreciate any help, as I can't find any solution.